# Apache Storm and Kafka integration with Firebase

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database, apache-kafka, apache-storm

```
    import backtype.storm.Config;`enter code here`
    import backtype.storm.`StormSubmitter`;`enter code here
    import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;`enter code here`
    import consumer.bolt.FirebaseBolt;`enter code here`
    import consumer.bolt.WordCountBolt;
    import consumer.bolt.WordCountDumpBolt;
    import nl.minvenj.nfi.storm.kafka.KafkaSpout;

    /**
     * User: tonymeng
     * Date: 3/31/14
     */
    public class FirebaseTopologyCluster {

      public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception {
        if (args == null || args.length != 3) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("localhost:2181 ,testTopic, https://chem-9b445.firebaseio.com/");
        }
        String zkConnect = args[0];
        String topic = args[1];
        String firebaseNamespace = args[2];

        Config config = new Config();
        config.setNumWorkers(1);

        config.put("kafka.spout.topic", topic);
        config.put("kafka.spout.consumer.group", "test-consumer-group");
        config.put("kafka.zookeeper.connect", zkConnect);
        config.put("kafka.consumer.timeout.ms", 4000);

        KafkaSpout spout = new KafkaSpout();
        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("kafkaspout", spout);
        builder.setBolt("countbolt", new WordCountBolt()).shuffleGrouping("kafkaspout");
        builder.setBolt("countfilebolt", new WordCountDumpBolt("/tmp/stats")).shuffleGrouping("countbolt");
        // using '`' as a delimiter
        builder.setBolt("firebasebolt", new FirebaseBolt(firebaseNamespace, "`")).shuffleGrouping("countbolt");

        StormSubmitter.submitTopology("statstopology", config, builder.createTopology());
      }
    }
```

This is my code. After this run show me this type of message. I wrote it above. How can I fix this issue:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: localhost:2181 ,testTopic, chem-9b445

Comment: Looks like you need to supply three parameters (zookeeper, topic, and firebase namespace) when you're trying to run it. BTW I don't think this is your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are throwing that exception.

```
if (args == null || args.length != 3) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("localhost:2181 ,testTopic, https://chem-9b445.firebaseio.com/");
}
```

while running you should pass 3 args to run this code properly.

these parameters are;

```
String zkConnect = args[0];
String topic = args[1];
String firebaseNamespace = args[2];
```